# Open specific terminals on login

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, session

I always have a ton of terminals opened doing certain things so when I have reboot it always takes me a decent amount of time to go back through and set them all back up. Is there any way for me to have a good bit of terminals open at login and start their monitoring, etc?

A good example could be: at login to Gnome, open a gnome-terminal that is already vim'd to file.txt, another one that opens with top, one that opens that is already SSHd to a different server, etc.

It looks like saving your session used to be a feature in the past but got dropped around 12. Im on Ubuntu 16.04. Can't seem to make this work...

Thanks yall for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first approach that comes to mind is to create a script with the  command lines to launch all the terminals you want, than map the execution of that script to a specific key combination.

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/sh
xterm -e tail -f /var/log/syslog &
xterm -e ssh localhost &
exit 0
```

Another approach would be using the `screen` utility and create a tailored configuration file to start as many shells you need with the appropriate commands executed. For example:

```
hardstatus  on
hardstatus  alwayslastline
hardstatus  string "%w%=%m/%d %c"
screen -t "syslog"      0 tail -f /var/log/syslog
screen -t "ssh"         1 ssh localhost
```